# How to show the content of an email in a webpage?

Tags: php, email

I'm workin with PHP imap and Gmail.
I want to show the content of an email in a webpage.
However when I get the check the code, it has
-break lines everywhere
-"=3D" characters in all the source.
Is there a way to get the mail body for a webpage?

Example:

```
 width: 24px; padding: 0pt;">&#160;</td>               <td style=3D"bord=
```

er-bottom: 1px solid rgb(202, 192, 182);" colspan=3D"4" class=3D"separat=
eur_logo">

Comment: You didnt format your code properly

Answer (score 1):

These =3D are how equal signs (=) are represented if the mail is encoded in quoted-printable style. You might want to read about quoted-printable in order to understand how you have to pase the mail’s source code.

Even better though would be to use one of the available e-mail parsing classes for PHP, since the subject is quite complex.

Comment: thanks Scytale.
I thought it would be a simple thing, but I have discovered a new world. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable